# How can I write conditional clauses using SQLAlchemy's expression language?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

So, I wrote quite a complicated query that fetches and joins a bunch of data from two tables.

```
SELECT
    /* Common attributes */
    carrier.name,
    carrier.notes,
    carrier.turnaround,

    /* Either per-reseller price, generic reseller price or default price */
    IFNULL(
        rsu.price,
        IF(
            (
                carrier.reseller_price != IS NOT NULL AND
                carrier.reseller_price != 0
            ),
            carrier.reseller_price,
            carrier.price
        )
    ) AS price,
    IFNULL(
        rsu.price_barred,
        IF(
            (
                carrier.reseller_price_barred IS NOT NULL AND
                carrier.reseller_price_barred != 0
            ),
            carrier.reseller_price_barred,
            carrier.price_barred
        )
    ) AS price_barred
FROM
    `core_carrier` AS carrier
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `core_resellerunlock` AS rsu ON (
        rsu.carrier_id = carrier.id AND
        rsu.reseller_id = 1
    )
```

*Can someone suggest a way of rewriting this using the SQLAlchemy query builder?* I'm not sure if it's even possible with those `SELECT ... IF` clauses.

**Edit:** I don't want to do this using ORM (and as far as I know, executing this using SQLAlchemy ORM purely is not possible). I'm just looking for a more or less portable way of doing this using SQLAlchemy's core.

Comment: Post the models will be helpful.

Comment: There are no models. Do you mean the DB schemas?

Comment: SQLAlchemy best feature is its ORM feature. When I say model, I am talking about the ORM. Schema is okay, but I hope you are not defining a raw schema though. I mean you can even just copy and paste the schema from your MySQL conole. Either way, with complete schema it's easier to read.

Comment: @CppLearner SQLAlchemy consists of two distinct parts - the core and the ORM layer. I'm only using the core.

Comment: I thought guy still needed to declare models when using the Core, and that it only saves you all the overhead in state management.  Anyways, I'm not sure this can be cleanly done in SqlAlchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a conditional in your query using [the `case` function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case). This won't produce exactly the SQL you presented, but can produce something functionally equivalent.

Here's a simple example, with the `carrier` and `rsu` variables referring to `Table` objects, and `case` referring to the aforementioned function:

```
join = carrier.join(rsu, (rsu.c.carrier_id == carrier.c.id) & (rsu.c.reseller_id == 1))
query = join.select([
    carrier.c.name,
    carrier.c.notes,
    carrier.c.turnaround,
    case([
        (
            rsu.c.price_barred == None,
            case([
                (
                    (carrier.c.reseller_price != None) & (carrier.c.reseller_price != 0),
                    carrier.c.reseller_price
                )
            ],
            else_=carrier.c.price
        )
    ]
])
```

You might find it convenient to make some helper functions to represent your higher-level `IFNULL` and `IF` functions to improve the readability of your query. For example:

```
def if_(expr, then, else_):
    return case([
        (expr, then)
    ], else_=else_)
```